# Lucene query: bla~* (match words that start with something fuzzy), how?

Tags: lucene, wildcard, fuzzy-search

In the Lucene query syntax I'd like to combine * and ~ in a valid query similar to: 
bla~* //invalid query

Meaning: Please match words that begin with "bla" or something similar to "bla".

**Update**:
What I do now, works for small input, is use the following (snippet of SOLR schema):

```
<fieldtype name="text_ngrams" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

In case you don't use SOLR, this does the following.

**Indextime**: Index data by creating a field containing all prefixes of my (short) input.

**Searchtime**: only use the ~ operator, as prefixes are explicitly present in the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe Lucene supports anything like this, nor do I believe it has a trivial solution.

"Fuzzy" searches do not operate on a fixed number of characters. `bla~` may for example match `blah` and so it must consider the entire term.

What you could do is implement a query expansion algorithm that took the query `bla~*` and converted it into a series of OR queries

```
bla* OR blb* OR blc OR .... etc.
```

But that is really only viable if the string is very short or if you can narrow the expansion based on some rules.

Alternatively if the length of the prefix is fixed you could add a field with the substrings and perform the fuzzy search on that. That would give you what you want, but will only work if your use case is sufficiently narrow.

You don't specify exactly why you need this, perhaps doing so will elicit other solutions.

One scenario I can think of is dealing with different form of words. E.g. finding `car` and `cars`.

This is easy in English as there are word stemmers available. In other languages it can be quite difficult to implement word stemmers, if not impossible.

In this scenario you can however (assuming you have access to a good dictionary) look up the search term and expand the search programmatically to search for all forms of the word.

E.g. a search for `cars` is translated into `car OR cars`. This has been applied successfully for my language in at least one search engine, but is obviously non-trivial to implement.

Comment: Althoug fuzzy searches don't operate on a fixed number of characters, for my case simply using ~ wont work (to big diff in char count). I want to match e.g. Sunla to Sundlaugarvegur.

Comment: of course, if i could tell lucene to only match on the first x characters of each word in the index, using ~ would work...

Comment: You would need to go beyond Lucene here, use a string comparison algorithm like Levenstein, Jaro-Winkler etc. (qv. below)

Answer (score 8):

in the development trunk of lucene (not yet a release), there is code to support use cases like this, via AutomatonQuery. Warning: the APIs might/will change before its released, but it gives you the idea.

Here is an example for your case:

```
// a term representative of the query, containing the field. 
// the term text is not so important and only used for toString() and such
Term term = new Term("yourfield", "bla~*");

// builds a DFA that accepts all strings within an edit distance of 2 from "bla"
Automaton fuzzy = new LevenshteinAutomata("bla").toAutomaton(2);

// concatenate this DFA with another DFA equivalent to the "*" operator
Automaton fuzzyPrefix = BasicOperations.concatenate(fuzzy, BasicAutomata.makeAnyString());

// build a query, search with it to get results.
AutomatonQuery query = new AutomatonQuery(term, fuzzyPrefix);
```

Comment: I just came back to this question, and saw your answer again. Have you tried it? What I'm doing now (works for small input), is to generate all prefixes of my input and put the prefixes in the index. Then I only need to use the ~ operator, and get functionality like ~*

Comment: Your workaround is just fine for small inputs... but as you hinted, will be a problem for large inputs: you will add a huge amount of terms and postings for all these prefixes... this will make the pre-Lucene 4.0 fuzzy query even slower as it does a linear scan of all terms.

Comment: Is there a Lucene query syntax that gives you access to the Automaton query through Solr without coding?

Answer (score 1):

It's for an address search service, where I want to suggest addresses based on partially typed and possibly mistyped streetnames/citynames/etc (any combination). (think ajax, users typing partial street addresses in a text field)

For this case the suggested query expansion is perhaps not so feasible, as the partial string (street address) may become longer than "short" :)

**Normalization**

One possibility I can think of is to use string "normalization", instead of fuzzy searches, and simply combine that with wildcard queries. A street address of

`"miklabraut 42, 101 reykjavík"`, would become `"miklabrat 42 101 rekavik"` when normalized.

**So, building index like this**:

1) build the index with records containing "normalized" versions of street names, city names etc, with one street address per document (1 or several fields).

**And search the index like this**:

2) Normalize inputstrings (e.g. `mikl reyk`) used to form the queries (i.e. `mik rek`).
3) use the wildcard op to perform the search (i.e. `mik* AND rek*`), leaving the fuzzy part out.

That would fly, provided the normalization algorithm is good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you wish to combine a wildcard and fuzzy query? You could use a boolean query with an OR condition to combine, for example:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();

Query q1 = //here goes your wildcard query
bq.Add(q1, BooleanClause...)

Query q2 = //here goes your fuzzy query
bq.Add(q2, BooleanClause...)
```

Comment: I do not believe this would accomplish what the OP is asking as it would basically become "bar~ OR bar*" which is not the same thing as "bar~*" and would not find (for example) "brafoo".

Comment: yup, this is not what I want :)

Comment: Ok,  thanks for clarifying, one approach I have used (for matching names of proteins etc.) using string distances like Smith-Waterman, Jaro-Winkler etc. A tool like SimMetrics might be of some help

http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/simmetrics.html

Comment: This is the second time I hear of SimMetrics, maybe it's time to give it a spin :) thank you