# Lucene.net Fuzzy Phrase Search

Tags: lucene.net, fuzzy-search, lucene, fuzzy-comparison

I have tried this myself for a considerable period and looked everywhere around the net - but have been unable to find ANY examples of Fuzzy Phrase searching via Lucene.NET 2.9.2. ( C# )

Is something able to advise how to do this in detail and/or provide some example code - I would seriously seriously appreciate any help as I am totally stuck ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631206/lucene-query-bla-match-words-that-start-with-something-fuzzy-how

Comment: yeah would love some code or anything related to fuzzy phrase searching in Lucene 2.9.2

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have Lucene running and created a search index with some fields in it. So let's assume further that:

```csharp
var fields = ... // a string[] of the field names you wish to search in
var version = Version.LUCENE_29; // your Lucene version
var queryString = "some string to search for";
```

Once you have all of these you can go ahead and define a search query on multiple fields like this:

```csharp
var analyzer = LuceneIndexProvider.CreateAnalyzer();
var query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(version, fields, analyzer).Parse(queryString);
```

Maybe you already got that far and are only missing the fuzzy part. I simply add a tilde `~` to every word in the `queryString` to tell Lucene to do a fuzzy search for all words in the queryString:

```csharp
if (fuzzy && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString)) {
    // first escape the queryString so that e.g. ~ will be escaped
    queryString = QueryParser.Escape(queryString);
    // now split, add ~ and join the queryString back together
    queryString = string.Join("~ ",
        queryString.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) + "~";
    // now queryString will be "some~ string~ to~ search~ for~"
}
```

The key point here is that Lucene uses fuzzy search only for terms that end with a `~`. That and some more helpful info was found on
http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/performing-a-fuzzy-search-with-multiple-terms-through-multiple-lucene-net-document-fields/.