# Neo4j, Neography: Making search smarter

Tags: search, neo4j, full-text-indexing, neography

I had been using [`full-text-indexes`](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) to search through the neo4j graph database. But in case the user enters a wrong spelling or the query doesn't match any result. Is there a way to handle this or a `did you mean` kind of feature in such cases?

Also how can the search be made smarter based on the what queries a user is searching? I came across [SearchKick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) but this doesn't have any integration with neography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce fuzziness into your lucene query. You can do it by appending a '~' sign to your query and specify the factor, e.g. `name:mistqke~0.8` should still find the text "mistake". The fuzziness factor is between 0 and 1. A value closer to 1 will match with a higher similarity.

If you want to combine a wildcard and a fuzzy query, you'll could use something like this:

```
START n=node:index('name:mistqke~0.8 or name:*mistqke*')
RETURN DISTINCT n;
```

Mind the 'OR' in the lucene query and 'DISTINCT' in the RETURN clause.

Comment: Hi, This is interesting.. 
but to match a partial string I am using `name:mistqke*~0.8` which is not taking fuzziness into account. While using `*` after the fuzziness factor gives `name:mistqke~0.8*` `Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure`...
How to handle such a case?

Comment: I don't think you can combine a wildcard and a fuzzy query actually. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631206/lucene-query-bla-match-words-that-start-with-something-fuzzy-how.

Comment: Thanks. I have somehow avoided that use case, and this currently works for me.